# Highlight or color the values of a specific row in table fetched using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am a beginner to PHP. I am looking to highlight or color the values of first and last row in a table fetched using PHP and Mysql. 
[image: Expected output]

Below is the code.

```
 <?php
  $result_trend = mysql_query("select Week, New_Tickets, Closed_Tickets, 
  Backlogged, Resolution_Rate, Transactions from table");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_trend))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Week'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['New_Tickets'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Closed_Tickets'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Backlogged'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Resolution_Rate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Transactions'] . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
  ?>
```

I am not really sure how to proceed further. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a `css` class and assign it to the desired rows

Comment: You can use CSS instead of PHP. Look up `first-child` and `last-child` selectors.

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a CSS style for the first and last rows as below:

```css
.my-table tbody tr:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>row</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Assuming `<table class="my_table">`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply obtain number of results and then count iterations. And if this is 1. row or last, add the style you need or css class that you'll style in your css file. Like this:

```
 <?php
  $result_trend = mysql_query("select Week, New_Tickets, Closed_Tickets, 
  Backlogged, Resolution_Rate, Transactions from table");
  $rows_count = mysql_num_rows($result_trend);
  $i = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_trend))
  {
  $i++;
  $style = "";
  if($i == 1 || $i == $rows_count) {
  //  $style .= "bgcolor=\"#FF0000\""   //for inline style, bad practise
      $style .= "class=\"colorful\""
  }
  echo "<tr " . $style . ">";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Week'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['New_Tickets'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Closed_Tickets'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Backlogged'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Resolution_Rate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Transactions'] . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
  ?>
```